# Specify custom WSL path when using Docker Desktop on Windows

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, docker-for-windows

When installing WSL updates manually, it installs to `C:\Program Files\WSL`, but the default `wsl.exe` exists in `System32` so when Docker Desktop calls `wsl` it doesn't use the new version.

Is there a way to specify a custom path to `wsl.exe` for Docker Desktop to use?

I can't use `wsl --update` because the system has no internet access

Comment: Are you sure you have the current version of WSL from the Windows Store installed? Sounds like you have the legacy WSL installed

Comment: This is a 21H2 install of Windows, its a bespoke OEM image with windows updates disabled. Probably don't have the version from Windows Store installed no

Comment: Can you give more details on how "bespoke" your Windows image is? Can you update the WSL version in the image prior to deployment?

Comment: @jossgray - You should make those details clear by editing your question.